# Vimperator-like addon for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-addons, vimperator

Is there any vimperator-like addon for Intenet Explorer? I'm most interested in something like the 'QuickHint' mode (in which you press 'f' and an unique number is assigned to every visible link(and typíng the number is equivalent to clicking the link)).

PS: I don't wanna sound rude but I really like IE and I'm not interested in answers like "use plugin xyz that makes Firefox looks like/behave like IE".

Thanks in advance.